# Integers converted to strings do not work as expected

Tags: processing

Issue comparing str() to what I'd expect is their String form

Code :

```
int i = 2;
String r = str(i);
println(r);
if (r == "2") {
  println("String works");
} else println("String doesnt work");
if (i == 2) {
  println("Integer works");
} else println("Integer doesnt work");
```

Prints :

> 2
> String doesnt work
> Integer works

The second if statement is a copy paste of the first, with only the variable and value changed so theres nothing wrong with my if statement

Processing documentation states (about str()):

> Converts a value of a primitive data type (boolean, byte, char, int, or float) to its String
> representation. For example, converting an integer with str(3) will return the String value of "3",
> converting a float with str(-12.6) will return "-12.6", and converting a boolean with str(true) will
> return "true".

Also doesnt work with str(2) == "2" or str(i) == "2"

How do I fix this and get it to work (without converting it back to an integer because that would make my code a bit ugly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare `String` values using `==`. Use the `equals()` function instead:

```java
if (r.equals("2")) {
```

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the `equals()` method, as in `if (a.equals(b))`, instead of `if (a == b)`. A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the `equals()` method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting#why-dont-these-strings-equal) reference has a longer explanation.)

More info here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)